# using textfield of second view in first view

Tags: iphone

I'm making a client-server program for iphone and i want to use my serverIP which is a part of my second view in the first view serverIP is a uitextfield. i use to enter the value of ServerIP in second View but i want to use the value of serverIP IN Firstview.

""secondview.h"" interface file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface secondview : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIView *view;
    IBOutlet UITextField *serverIP;
    IBOutlet UITextField *noc;
    IBOutlet UIButton *save;
    IBOutlet UIButton *back;
    IBOutlet UIButton *load;
     IBOutlet UILabel *display1;
}

-(IBAction) back;
-(IBAction) save;
-(IBAction) load;

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *serverIP; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *noc;
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UILabel *display1;


@end
```

""secondview.m"" implementation file

```
#import "secondview.h"


@implementation secondview


@synthesize serverIP,noc,display1;


-(IBAction) save{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:serverIP forKey:@"save"]; 

    NSUserDefaults *myname = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];



    [serverIP resignFirstResponder];



}

-(IBAction) load {

    serverIP = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"load"];

    NSUserDefaults *myname = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];





}


-(IBAction) back {

    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serverIP is textField. You can get the text in it as serverIp.text
So you can save it in user default as

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:serverIp.text forKey:@"save"];
```

You were trying to save the text field itself as integer in user defaults, which is incorrect.

To retrieve it, use

```
NSString *serverIpString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"];
```

Comment: @ pratikshabhisikar it doesnt work and it displays a warning in load function "unused variable serveripstring

Comment: Ofcourse it will say unused variable serveripString if you retrieve it from user defaults and do nothing with it. The point is, are you getting correct serverip string from the user defaults?

Answer (score 0):

Do this to save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:serverIP.text forKey:@"save"];
```

and to retrieve:

```
NSString *serverIPSTR = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"load"];
```

Comment: what error are you receiving? by the way the problems in the code you posted are:

You are trying to set a TextField inside NSUserDefaults (you can't do that), and also using integerForKey which (as the name implies) stores integers.

Comment: @ giuliano galea i m not receiving any error but when  i load then nothing is displayed.

Comment: I see, do this also: `serverIp.text = serverIPSTR;`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"load"] != nil) {
    serverIP = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"load"];
} else {
    serverIP = @"Your default IP address";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:serverIP ForKey:@"load"];
}
```

Instead of 'load' though I would use something less likely to clash with defaults such as

**myappname_serverip**